# Why does only one of the cron jobs not run

Tags: php, cron

So I got around to needing cron jobs. So I wrote the cron but now i only see that it fails all the time.

This is the cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://fetch.project-sato.net/statuschecker/performcheck.php?key=insertyourkeyhere
```

I replace the url cause its smth no one here needs to know about and yes I confirmed that the url works because a bought webserver of my friend runs the cron without a problem.

The error im getting:

```
May 23 20:36:00 DoomMachine-v1 systemd[1]: cron-root-2.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=8/n/a
May 23 20:36:00 DoomMachine-v1 systemd[1]: Failed to start [Cron] "* * * * * wget -q -O temp.txt http://fetch.project-sato.net/statuschecker/performcheck.php?key=insertyourkeyhere".
May 23 20:36:00 DoomMachine-v1 systemd[1]: Unit cron-root-2.service entered failed state.
```

If I run the command of the cron in the terminal it works fine but the cron seems to have a problem.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should write full path to `temp.txt` file instead of relative, for example `/tmp/temp.txt`